# How to find/extract an HTML "font" element with attribute size="+1" using Excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I want to extract a U.S. Patent title from a url like

http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=6293874.PN.&OS=PN/6293874&RS=PN/6293874

(Update: as pointed out the comments, the patent title is not labeled "Title;" however, it consistently appears by itself above "Abstract" on the web page.) In most cases it is in the 7th child element of "body" or the 3rd "font" element in the document, but occasionally a notice at the top of the page to "** Please see images for: ( Certificate of Correction ) **" or "( Reexamination Certificate )" messes up both methods of extraction by inserting one additional child of "body" and three additional "font" elements before you get to the title.

However, the title seems to be consistently the first "font" element with the attribute "size" having a value of "+1".  Unfortunately other elements have size="-1", including the aforementioned elements that are not always present, so it has to be specifically with that attribute and value.  I have searched but can't figure out how to get elements by attribute and value.  Here is my code:

```
Function Test_UpdateTitle(url As String)
    Dim title As String
    Dim pageSource As String
    Dim xml_obj As XMLHTTP60
    Set xml_obj = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    xml_obj.Open "GET", url, False
    xml_obj.send
    pageSource = xml_obj.responseText
    Set xml_obj = Nothing

    Dim html_doc As HTMLDocument
    Set html_doc = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
    html_doc.body.innerHTML = pageSource
    Dim fontElement As IHTMLElement

'Methods 1 and 2 fail in cases of a certificate of correction or reexamination certificate

'Method 1

'    Dim body As IHTMLElement
'    Set body = html_doc.getElementsByTagName("body").Item(0)
'    Set fontElement = body.Children(6)

'Method 2
'    Set fontElement = html_doc.getElementsByTagName("font").Item(3)

'Method 3

    Dim n As Integer
    For n = 3 To html_doc.getElementsByTagName("font").Length - 1
        Set fontElement = html_doc.getElementsByTagName("font").Item(n)
        If InStr(fontElement.innerText, "Please see") = 0 And _
        InStr(fontElement.innerText, "( Certificate of Correction )") = 0 And _
        InStr(fontElement.innerText, "( Reexamination Certificate )") = 0 And _
        InStr(fontElement.innerText, " **") = 0 Then
            Test_UpdateTitle = fontElement.innerText
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next n

End Function
```

I should add that the " **" is not working to skip the the last element `<b> **</b>` and I am getting " **" as the title where there is a notice to please see images.  Is asterisk a wildcard character in this context?

Comment: ++ for not parsing HTML with Regex!

Comment: Appreciate it Mat - was tempted to use Regex lookarounds but fought the urge

Comment: What is the "title" text you want to extract from the example you sent?  I can't find the word "title" in that page.

Comment: "User-operated amusement apparatus for kicking the user's buttocks" - a watershed patent in the self-butt-kicking field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. As long as its the first font tag with the size attribute and a value of "+1" this should work. I only tested with 3 different pages but they all returned the correct results.

```
Function Test_UpdateTitle(url)
    title = "Title Not Found!"
    Set xml_obj = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    xml_obj.Open "GET", url, False
    xml_obj.send
    pageSource = xml_obj.responseText
    Set xml_obj = Nothing

    Set document = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
    document.write pageSource   

    For i = 0 To document.getElementsByTagName("font").length - 1
        If document.getElementsByTagName("font")(i).size = "+1" Then
            title = document.getElementsByTagName("font")(i).innerText
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Test_UpdateTitle = title

End Function

MsgBox Test_UpdateTitle("http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=6293874.PN.&OS=PN/6293874&RS=PN/6293874")
MsgBox Test_UpdateTitle("http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&co1=AND&d=PTXT&s1=fight.TI.&OS=TTL/fight&RS=TTL/fight")
MsgBox Test_UpdateTitle("http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-adv.htm&r=14&f=G&l=50&d=PTXT&p=1&S1=search&OS=search&RS=search")
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is somewhat incomplete because my Excel won't do these lines:

```
Dim xml_obj As XMLHTTP60
Set xml_obj = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
```

But I think this might be a preferred approach.

Instead of using USPTO's site, what about using Google's?

Hit this URL: http://www.google.com/patents/US6293874

Note that the patent number is apparent in that URL.

Then, in your function, just pull that tag named `invention-title`.

```
Set titleElement = html_doc.getElementsByTagName("invention-title").Item(0)
title = titleElement.innerText
MsgBox(title)
```

If you check the source on that page, there's only one of those.

If you're open to this alternative approach, it would be relatively easy to parse patent numbers from the URLs you have, and I think the extraction of `invention-title` would be much more reliable.

Comment: I had found that Google Patents pages would deny http get requests from Jsoup, but it hadn't even occurred to me to see if it would allow access by MSXML.  I will give it a try.  However, you should be aware that Google Patents has a few issues for consistent patent downloading: 1) Google's pdf documents are not updated for a Certificate of Correction or Reexamination Certificate, which can substantively affect the scope of a patent, especially the latter; 2) there are occasional unexplained gaps in Google's records; and 3) Google Patents lags behind USPTO in publication by a week or more.

Comment: Also, Google can give you a false sense that its pdf's are OCR'ed - last I checked, if the document has 20+ pages containing recognizable text, it stops after the 20th.  So if you text search a patent PDF from Google, you may incorrectly conclude that your search string isn't there, in case it shows up somewhere farther down.

Comment: I only discovered these obscure tidbits about Google Patents through a year and a half of developing (Java and VBA) tools for use in my own practice =P

Comment: Of course none of the above is legal advice and you should consult a patent attorney if you have any questions about your own rights.

Comment: Sorry I don't mean get requests but parsing methods; Google allows Jsoup to connect and download a patent document, but I couldn't manage to get at the html document (granted I am still a newbie programmer).

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, @PatentWookiee.  I hadn't considered the broader issues with using Google Patents.  Was just trying to get you a title!  Good luck.

Comment: Those are only the negatives - Google patents has a lot of pluses too, including the one you discovered about a dedicated title HTML element, In addition to a lot of cross-linking and status info contained in the HTML

Answer (score 1):

See if this answer is working as intended. Make sure you have references to the following libraries in your workbook:

Microsoft XML, v6.0
Microsoft HTML Object Library

[image: Libraries used]

If you are not sure how to add these to Excel just give a read to this link [Link to reference adding](http://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-reference-libraries-in-excel-workbook/)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Debug.Print Test_UpdateTitle("http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=6293874.PN.&OS=PN/6293874&RS=PN/6293874")

End Sub

Function Test_UpdateTitle(ByVal strURL As String) As String


    Dim oHTTP As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim oDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim oFontTags As Variant
    Dim oFontTag As HTMLFontElement
    Dim strInnerText As String
    Dim strSize As String

    ' Create the http object and send it.
    Set oHTTP = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    oHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False
    oHTTP.send


    ' Make sure that get the a reponse back
    If oHTTP.Status = 200 Then

        Set oDoc = New HTMLDocument
        oDoc.body.innerHTML = oHTTP.responseText

        Set oFontTags = oDoc.getElementsByTagName("font")

        ' Go through all the tags.
        For Each oFontTag In oFontTags

            'Get the inner text and size of each tag.
            strInnerText = oFontTag.innerText
            strSize = oFontTag.getAttributeNode("size").Value

                        'Compare to make sure you have what's needed
            If InStr(strInnertText, "Please see") = 0 And _
               InStr(strInnertText, "( Certificate of Correction )") = 0 And _
               InStr(strInnertText, "( Reexamination Certificate )") = 0 And _
               InStr(strInnertText, " **") = 0 Then

                If strSize = "+1" Then
                    Test_UpdateTitle = strInnerText
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        Next oFontTag
    End If

End Function
```

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: I like the contribution of checking the HTTP status - I only picked Sean Wessell's answer because it addresses how to get at the "size" attribute.  Also, as I noted above, my "InStr(strInnerText, " **") = 0" seems not to match the html element  <b> **</b> .  I was not sure why, but could it be treating asterisk as a wildcard?

Comment: Not a problem. He replied first :) Also we are getting the size in two different ways: strSize = oFontTag.getAttributeNode("size").Value.

Comment: Oh somehow I missed that you were also getting the size

Answer (score 0):

In short:

```
Debug.Print html_doc.querySelector("font[size=+1]").innerText
```

---

## tl;dr;

**① CSS selector:**

No need for any of the long winded methods. You have stated the styling pattern. Use a CSS selector to grab it.

```
font[size=+1]
```

The reads as `font` tag with attribute `size` who value is `+1`. You may need `font[size='+1']` when using VBA to try both.

---

**② CSS query:**

[image: CSS query]

---

**③ VBA:**

As it is the first match you want you can use the `querySelector` method of `document` to apply the selector and retrieve a single element.

```
 html_doc.querySelector("font[size=+1]")
```

You may need to add a reference to `HTML Object Library` and use an early bound call of `Dim html_doc As HTMLDocument` to access the method. The late bound method may expose the `querySelector` method but if the interface doesn't then use early binding.